# useEffect dependency warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

I am working on a reactjs web application.

Here is my code source:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

...

function myPage() {
    async function myPageLoad() {
        ...
    }

    useEffect(() => { myPageLoad(); }, []);


    return (<div>My page content</div>);
}

export default myPage;
```

I want myPageLoad to be called when the page is displayed (initialization). Please note i will also call this function when i want to refresh my page's informations.

Can you confirm me useEffect is the good way to call myPageLoad function ? Or is there another way to do that ?

It seems to work but i get this warning at runtime:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'myPageLoad'. Either
> include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I have tried to put myPageLoad in dependency array but it does not work.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you have to update your myPageLoad function as `useCallback` function:

```
const myPageLoad = useCallback(async () => {
   ...
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  myPageLoad();
}, [myPageLoad]);
```

This guarantees that the myPageLoad function identity is stable and won’t change on any re-renders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with your method, i cannot call myPageLoad() from a button click for example

Comment: Of course you can! Why is it that you could not?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution

```
useEffect(() => { 
    async function myPageLoad() {
        ...
    }
    myPageLoad()
 }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks but it won't be possible to call myPageLoad from outside (when i click on a button for example)